# Вызов JavaScript кода после метода бина

Tags: java, jsf

Как сделать при нажатии на кнопку`h:commandButton`, в начале что бы отработал метод бина, а потом `JS` код.

Comment: Что такое метод бина?

Comment: И еще - java и javascript это разные языки. Уберите лишний тег.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться ajax вызовом и повесить обработчик на него.

страница

```
<h:commandButton ...>
   <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.method}" onevent="hendler" .../>
</h:commandButton>
```

js

```
function hendler(data) {
    switch (data.status) {
        case "begin": // До отправления запроса
            break;

        case "complete": // Поле получения ответа на запрос
            break;

        case "success": // После применения обновлений запроса
            break;
    }
}
```

В зависимости от характера действий на вашей кнопке вызов js функции можно вставить либо в ситуации `complete` либо `success`